# Photo and video slideshow digital signage

Tags: video

I am building a digital signage solution using a Raspberry Pi and would I like to play photo and video randomly, in an endless loop, whilst in full screen mode.

Is there a ready-made open-source freeware for such a function already?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using only one screen at a time, then Screenly OS is a good choice. There is a ready-to-use image available for the pi. https://www.screenly.io/ose/

It can display photos, videos and URLs. And it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to read up on other similar projects the term you're looking for is 'kiosk'. We have a tag and a few dozen hits on it [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk) already.

Adafruit have a [detailed tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview) and some [associated software on Github](https://github.com/adafruit/pi_video_looper) for setting a Pi up to loop video. It shouldn't be too difficult to start from there and tweak it to your liking. Adafruit describe its basic operation as follows:

> After installation video looper is configured to play movies off of
>   USB drives inserted in the Raspberry Pi.  The default video player,
>   omxplayer, can play most videos encoded with the H.264 video codec and
>   in a video format with an extension like .avi, .mov, .mkv, .mp4, or
>   .m4v.  You can even play 720p and 1080p movies because omxplayer will
>   use the Pi's GPU (graphics processing unit) to efficiently play
>   videos!
>
> With video looper running if you insert a USB stick with movies a
>   message will display with the number of detected movies, and a 10
>   second countdown...

The only slightly unusual aspect to this approach is that the config files are stored in the Pi's boot partition. This means it's probaly easiest to pull the SD card and mount it on another machine to make any changes:

> The configuration file is stored in the /boot part of the Raspberry
>   Pi's SD card which means you can edit it directly on your computer. 
>   Shutdown your Raspberry Pi (see this page if you aren't sure how),
>   pull out the micro SD card, and insert it into your computer.  After
>   your computer displays the files on the card open the video_looper.ini
>   file in a text editor.

The config files are well commented, and shouldn't be too hard to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But actually would like to explore more about looping photo & video at the same time. Seems like the one you suggested is for video only. Is there such kind of project?

Comment: Openshot or Kdenlive allow compilation of video and images then bundling up into a single output video.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenELEC Kodi with a screensaver add on. This allows the screensaver to be set to a folder. Content can be updated using the Samba share.